# How to add 'slug' tag automatically in markdown files using NetlifyCMS and Gatsby?

Tags: node.js, graphql, gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

Codesandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/tvlei).

Any time I try to publish a new blog post using NetlifyCMS, it says it publishes. However my Netlify build fails and doesn't actually push any blog posts live.

Here's the error I get:

```
12:44:22 PM: error Your site's "gatsby-node.js" must set the page path when creating a page.
12:44:22 PM: The page object passed to createPage:
12:44:22 PM: {
12:44:22 PM:     "path": null,
12:44:22 PM:     "component": "/opt/build/repo/src/templates/blogTemplate.js",
12:44:22 PM:     "context": {
12:44:22 PM:         "slug": null
12:44:22 PM:     }
12:44:22 PM: }
12:44:22 PM: See the documentation for the "createPage" action — https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#createPage
12:44:22 PM: not finished createPages - 0.042s
```

The reason why I get this error is because when new posts are published, the markdown file of the new blog post does not automatically get the 'slug' tag added. Example:

```
---
title: 10 of the best SEO strategies for 2021
slug: /posts/10-best-seo-strategies-2021/ <-- I had to manually add this in the markdown file. This line is completely missing when pushing new blog posts live. This is causing the site build to fail.
date: 2021-03-26T23:53:24.128Z
excerpt: >-
  In this post, we go over 10 of the best SEO strategies for 2021. If you want
  more business, read more now!
---
```

Once I manually go and add the blog post as a markdown file outside of NetlifyCMS, and add the slug tag and push up to master, it successfully builds. Obviously I don't want to do that every time, I want my site to publish normally from NetlifyCMS.

**gatsby-node.js:**

```
exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const blogPostTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/blogTemplate.js`)
  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
        limit: 1000
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  // Handle errors
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }
  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.frontmatter.slug,
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      context: {
        // additional data can be passed via context
        slug: node.frontmatter.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

**GraphQL pageQuery in my /src/pages/posts.js file:**

```
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query {
    allMarkdownRemark(sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }) {
      edges {
        node {
          id
          excerpt(pruneLength: 250)
          frontmatter {
            date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
            slug
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

**Config.yml:**

```
backend:
  name: github
  repo: my-repo

media_folder: uploads
public_folder: /uploads

collections:
  - name: "posts"
    label: "Posts"
    folder: "posts"
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    fields:
      - { label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Publish Date", name: "date", widget: "date" }
      - { label: "Excerpt", name: "excerpt", widget: "string" }
      - { label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown" }

blogTemplate.js file:

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query($slug: String!) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
        slug
        title
        excerpt
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Any idea why this may be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea why this may be happening?

Well, you are trying to query for a `slug` field and it's never been set (at least at the beginning). Your `frontmatter` has these fields:

- Title
- Publish
- Excerpt
- Body

But not a `slug`.

The standard way is to add it in your `config.yml`:

```
- { name: slug, label: Slug, required: true, widget: string }
```

Adding this, your query will work automatically.

Another method is to use the [built-in listeners and the resolvers (Node APIs)](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-apis/) from Gatsby to generate a `slug` based on a parameter previously set, but you will need to change your query. On your `gatsby-node.js` add:

```
exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions;

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    let value = createFilePath({ node, getNode });

    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value,
    });
  }
};
```

With `onCreateNode` you are creating a new node based on some rules ([more details](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/56c7f056b2234f6cc48badd53206cd881d99ce60/packages/gatsby/src/joi-schemas/joi.ts#L94-L114)). That will create a new collection to be queried named `fields` with a `slug` inside. So you only need to adapt it like:

```
exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql, reporter }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions
  const blogPostTemplate = require.resolve(`./src/templates/blogTemplate.js`)
  const result = await graphql(`
    {
      allMarkdownRemark(
        sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }
        limit: 1000
      ) {
        edges {
          node {
            fields{
              slug
            }
            frontmatter {
              slug // not needed now
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  // Handle errors
  if (result.errors) {
    reporter.panicOnBuild(`Error while running GraphQL query.`)
    return
  }
  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: blogPostTemplate,
      context: {
        // additional data can be passed via context
        slug: node.frontmatter.slug,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

There's no "automated" way to achieve this without diving into more Node schemas. You are only creating a markdown file and querying its content. Which are the logic to create a `slug` from scratch? `slug` fields should be always required.

You can try changing the following:

```
createNodeField({
  name: `slug`,
  node,
  value,
});
```

To add a custom `value` based on some logic if the `slug` is not defined.

---

Another thing outside the topic. You are creating duplicated an `excerpt`:

- One in your markdown (coming from Netlify's CMS):

  ```
  - { label: "Excerpt", name: "excerpt", widget: "string" }
  ```
- One created automatically in your GraphQL query. GraphQL + Gatsby filesystem adds a custom `excerpt` field that results from a splitting of the content of the `body` by using a `pruneLength` filtering outside the `frontmatter`:

  ```
    export const pageQuery = graphql`
      query {
        allMarkdownRemark(sort: { order: DESC, fields: [frontmatter___date] }) {
          edges {
            node {
              id
              excerpt(pruneLength: 250)
              frontmatter {
                date(formatString: "MMMM DD, YYYY")
                slug
                title
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  ```

I think that you are mixing stuff here, I would recommend using only one of them to avoid misunderstandings in your code.

Comment: Adding - { name: slug, label: Slug, required: true, widget: string } to my config.yml did it. Thanks Ferran!